# HttpPost methods do not support return type of System.RestResponse comes in Rest Web Service

Tags: rest-api, webservices

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/test/v1/')
global class ringcentralWebhook
{
    @HttpPost
    global static System.RestResponse doPost()
    {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String JsonBody = req.requestBody.toString();
        Map<String, Object> body = (Map<String, Object>)Json.deserializeUntyped(JsonBody);
        String s = String.valueOf(body);
        Map<String,Object> m = (Map<String,Object>)req.headers;
        String vt1 = String.valueOf(m.get('Validation-token'));
        contact c = new contact(lastName = 'test ringcentral again', description=vt1);
        insert c;
        String header = 'Validation-Token';
        //String VToken = req.params.get('validation-token');
        String st = header+'='+vt1;
        res.addHeader(header, vt1);
        //res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(''));
        res.statusCode = 200;
        //res.send();
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't have to explicitly return that. It can just be a void method:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/test/v1/')
global class ringcentralWebhook
{
    @HttpPost
    global static void doPost()
    {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String JsonBody = req.requestBody.toString();
        Map<String, Object> body = (Map<String, Object>)Json.deserializeUntyped(JsonBody);
        String s = String.valueOf(body);
        Map<String,Object> m = (Map<String,Object>)req.headers;
        String vt1 = String.valueOf(m.get('Validation-token'));
        contact c = new contact(lastName = 'test ringcentral again', description=vt1);
        insert c;
        String header = 'Validation-Token';
        //String VToken = req.params.get('validation-token');
        String st = header+'='+vt1;
        res.addHeader(header, vt1);
        //res.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serialize(''));
        res.statusCode = 200;
        //res.send();
        //return res;
    }
}
```